# reactNative TextInput number-pad not showing properly on android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, keyboard

Im using

> TextInput

with

> keyboardType = "number-pad"

On iOS it works fine, but on Android it shows normal keyboard, how do I make android show the number-pad keyboard, and hide the "suggest" bar

[image: screenshot mobiles]
On the left the iOS showing correctly, on the right the android emulator showing wrong keyboard.

```
<TextInput
    ref="second"
    style={this.state.pos > 0 ? styles.textInputStyle : 
    styles.textInputNormalStyle}
    keyboardType = "number-pad"
    maxLength={1}
    value={this.state.secondVal}
    onKeyPress={(event) => {this.onChange(1, event.nativeEvent.key); }}
```

/>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the [**docs**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardtype), you need to supply **keyboardType** as `phone-pad`.

`number-pad` is only for ***IOS***

For hiding the bar try `autoCorrect={false}`

**Edit**

As per the latest docs `number-pad` has been added for cross-platform support

Comment: 0.56 added cross platform support on number-pad. However the old 0.55 version did not https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.55/textinput#keyboardtype

Answer (score 0):

for me that `keyboardType='number-pad'` isn't working on Android yet even though the doc says it's available cross-platform! (which is quite weird)
so my solution was just validating the value before setting it as the input value

```
 const onChangeText = (text) => {
    setInputValue(text.replace(/\D/g, ""));
  };
```